# what to install on server to develop internet mobile application?

Tags: java-me

I'm creating a recommender system which most of calculations are going to be processed  on the server side. I've installed Netbeans and emulator, and tried the "Hello World" program. Every offline thing's fine.
To develop a recommender system, it is necessary to work online (i.e.,send and receive data from server). However, I have no clue about the technology used. What to install on the server? Or what I should set up next? thanks

Comment: call web service and send the data to server.

Comment: can you be more detailed? any name/brand of softwares needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HttpConnection](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wi-jio/) or use [soap](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/) for calling webservice.